# Просвечивается выпадающее меню, как исправить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Просвечивается выпадающее меню
Все элементы которые имеют свойсвто position:relative/absolute 
Появляются поверх выпадающей менюшки
middle-section просвечивает logo and nav ,пример на скрине
как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.logo {
      line-height: 60px;
      position: fixed;
      float: left;
      margin: 16px 46px;
      color: #fff;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      line-height: 60px;
}
.middle-section
{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Можно увидеть html разметку?

Answer (score 1):

За полупрозрачный фон отвечает в css :rgba(r,g,b,a); где a это сама прозрачность шкала от 0 до 1 т.е в моём случае это 0.95

для просмотра откройте пример во всю страницу а сам браузер сожмите до 768px

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        *{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
            text-decoration: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        ul{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
        }
        .section{
            width:90%;
            margin:auto;
            background:#fbfbfb;
        }
        .container{
            width:90%;
            margin:auto;
            text-align: center
        }
        .item{
            margin:50px 0;
        }
        .item p{
            text-align: left
        }
        @media(max-width:768px){
            ul{
                flex-direction: column;
                text-align: center;
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                left:50%;
                transform: translateX(-50%);
                background:rgba(0,0,0,0.95);
                width:100%;
                height:100vh;
                z-index: 9;
                display: none;
            }
            li{
                padding:10px 0;
                position: relative;
            }
            ul li:before{
                content:"";
                display:block;
                height: 3px;
                background:#fbfbfb;
                position: absolute;
                top:100%;
                left:50%;
                
                right:50%;
                transition: 0.35s;
            }
            ul li:hover:before{
                content:"";
                display:block;
                height: 3px;
                background:#fbfbfb;
                position: absolute;
                top:100%;
                left:25%;
                right:25%;
                transition: 0.35s;
            }

            ul li a{
                color:#fbfbfb;
                font-size:20px;
            }
            span.trigger{
                display:block;
                width:40px;
                height:30px;
                cursor:pointer;
                position: relative;
                z-index:100;
            }
            span.trigger i{
                display:block;
                width:90%;
                height:10px;
                background:#ccc;
                margin:5px auto;
            }
            .show{
                display:flex;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <span class="trigger">
       <i></i>
       <i></i>
       <i></i>
   </span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">text1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.html">text2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text4</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text5</a></li>
        <li><a href="">text6</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et hic sunt alias, amet fugit at consequatur explicabo doloribus molestiae magnam.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et hic sunt alias, amet fugit at consequatur explicabo doloribus molestiae magnam.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et hic sunt alias, amet fugit at consequatur explicabo doloribus molestiae magnam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
          $("span.trigger").on("click", function(){
              $("ul").toggleClass("show");
          });
          $("ul:not(li)").on("click", function(){
              $("ul").removeClass("show");
          });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```